# Como pintar tabla dinamicamente php sql server?

Tags: php, css, sql-server

Buenas Quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando que se muestren de mi query de un sp la columnas pero es dinámico es decir que algunos meses aparecen y algunos no, según el rango que escogían en el formulario.

Como yo no se que columnas se van a mostrar con este codigo en php me genera la columna dinamica.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
   /* Tu proceso de conexión, consulta y resultado */
   $sql= "EXEC Sp_DetalleObservacion 6,'','','','','','','' ";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");    

   if(!$result){
       echo "Ocurrio un error en la consulta"; 
   }else{
       $tabla ="<table class='table table-bordered text-center' id='tablenombrehistorico'>";
       $tabla .="<thead>";
       $tabla .= "<tr>";
       $i = 0;
       while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          if ($i == 0) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {                
              $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>" . $key . "</th>";
            }
            $tabla .="</tr>";
            $tabla .="</thead>";

            $tabla .="<tbody>";
          } 
          $tabla .="<tr>";
          foreach($data as $key => $value) {  

            if($value=="ZONA I - ADONIAS SILVA"  or $value=="ZONA II - DANNY CANELA" or $value=="ZONA III - SANDRO CHAVEZ")
            {
                $tabla .="<td style='background: yellow'>".$value."</td>";


            } 
            /*
          else if($value=="0.00")
           {

             $tabla .="<td style='background: yellow'>".$value."</td>";
           }
           */
            else
            {         
               $tabla .="<td>".$value."</td>";


             }

              //$tabla .="<td>".$value."</td>";
          }    
          $tabla .="</tr>";
          $i++;
       }
       $tabla .="</tbody>";
       $tabla .="</table>";
       echo $tabla; 
   }       
?>
```

actual mente se encuentra asi como la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo quisiera que se hiciera algo asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

basicamente si yo escogo una fecha ejemplo de enero o marzo se debe mostrar solo de esa fecha que ya lo hace dinamico pero lo que yo quiero es pintar asi como la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

rspuesa

```
<?php
include("config.php");
   /* Tu proceso de conexión, consulta y resultado */
   $sql= "EXEC Sp_DetalleObservacion 6,'','','','','','','' ";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");    

   if(!$result){
       echo "Ocurrio un error en la consulta"; 
   }else{
       $tabla ="<table class='table table-bordered text-center' id='tablenombrehistorico'>";
       $tabla .="<thead>";
       $tabla .= "<tr>";
       $i = 0;

while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($i == 0) {
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {                
          $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>" . $key . "</th>";
          $counter++;
          if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
            $tabla .= "<th style='background: black'>  </th>";
          }

        }
        $tabla .="</tr>";

        $tabla .="</thead>";

        $tabla .="<tbody>";


      }   
        $counter = 0;   

      foreach($data as $key => $value) {  
        if($value=="ZONA I - ADONIAS SILVA"  or $value=="ZONA II - DANNY CANELA" or $value=="ZONA III - SANDRO CHAVEZ")
        {
            $tabla .= "<tr style='background: yellow'>";                
        } elseif ($key == 'agencia') {                     
           $tabla .="<tr>";

        }            
        $tabla .="<td>".$value."</td>";            
      }
      $tabla .="</tr>";
      $i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedo ayudarte con el fondo amarillo:

```
while  ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($i == 0) {
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {                
          $tabla .="<th scope='col' style='text-align: center;background-color: #054AC4;color: #fff'>" . $key . "</th>";
          $counter++;
          if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
            $tabla .= "<th style='background: black'>  </th>";
          }
        }
        $tabla .="</tr>";
        $tabla .="</thead>";

        $tabla .="<tbody>";
      }           
      foreach($data as $key => $value) {  
        if($value=="ZONA I - ADONIAS SILVA"  or $value=="ZONA II - DANNY CANELA" or $value=="ZONA III - SANDRO CHAVEZ")
        {
            $tabla .= "<tr style='background: yellow'>";                
        } elseif ($key == 'agencia') {                     
           $tabla .="<tr>";

        }            
        $tabla .="<td>".$value."</td>";            
      }
      $tabla .="</tr>";
      $i++;
   }
```

Comment: me sale un erro linea 37 que es aqui:  $counter++;

Comment: habia dos problemacon tu codigo 1. que habias colocado dos {{ en el else if y otro que el variable $counter no existia ese variable lo cambie por $i++

Comment: tu crees que se podria eso del border

Comment: para que se diferencia en que mes cada uno asi como la imagen

Comment: Tienes razon, la variable `$counter` no deberia estar ahi, y si tenia dos `{{`, pero `$i++` no tienes que moverlo de lugar.

Comment: Para lo de el border de los meses, parece ser que las columnas se muestran de tres en tres, por lo que podrias crear un contador.  Cuando el contador sea divisible entre tres, agregas otra columna con fondo negro.

Comment: si es 3 en 3 contado como hermano

Comment: Un contador es simplemente una variable que va aumentando de valor en cada iteracion.  Por ejemplo la variable `$i` es un contador.  Necesitas crear otro contador que cuente las columnas.  Cuando el valor de ese contador sea divisible entre 3 agregas una nueva columna.

Comment: puedes hacer en tu rspyesa un ejemplo no soy bueno en php

Comment: Ya lo hice para los titulos de las columnas.  Necesitas hacer lo mismo con el cuerpo de la tabla.

Comment: hermano se descuadro puse la imagen en mi pregunta al final

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80719/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-pierro).

Comment: modifique la respuesta puse contador a 0 pero igual se descuadra